# Laravel seeder use same value in loop

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I need to add an extra uuid field to a table I'm using.
So I created a seeder which is getting all the rows in this table and adding a generated uuid for each row.

```
$retailerBrands = App\RetailerBrand::all();

        $retailerBrands->map(function($retailerBrand){
            $uuid = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
            var_dump("Value of uuid generated ", $uuid);
            $retailerBrand->uuid = $uuid; 
            $retailerBrand->save();
        });
```

But all my rows always end up with the same uuid (the first one generated), even if when I dump my generated uuid I can see that it is different at each loop. It seems as i it was caching the value the first time and using it on all the other loops.

I guess I'm doing something stupid here but I can't find out what.

Any help will be useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the given code.

```php
$retailerBrands = App\RetailerBrand::all();
foreach($retailerBrands as $rb){
    $rb->uuid = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
    $rb->save();
}
```

If it still doesn't work, make sure the static function `Uuid::generate()` generates unique id every time. You can check it by `dd()` function as,

```php
$a = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 50 ; $i++){
    $newVar = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
    array_push($a , $newVar);
}

//the output should contain 50 unique uuid
dd($a);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the result is exactly the same. Using a foreach instead of a collection map doesn't change anything, I still have the same uuid inserted for all the rows. I don't have that many rows so looping on each one isn't a problem.

Comment: Indeed I have checked it :) As you can see in my initial message I thought this could be the issue, that's why I've added a var_dump in my loop to check that it generates different uuid each time. I also tried with a rand() instead of generating uuid and the result is the same I end up with the same value for all my rows. I guess my issue is on the database insertion but I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

Comment: please post `Uuid::generate()` function here.

Comment: The package used to generate uuids is this one : https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid/blob/master/src/Webpatser/Uuid/Uuid.php 5I use version 4). But once again if I even use a simple PHP rand() instead of Uuid:generate() I still have the same problem, so the problem should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally found out what was going wrong.
Posting it here so someone with the same problem can search a little less longer than me.

It turns out that the previous code was running this query :

```
 0 => array:3 [
"query" => "update `retailer_brands` set `uuid` = ?, `retailer_brands`.`updated_at` = ? where `uuid` = ?"
"bindings" => array:3 [
  0 => "e0d20bef-1013-46b4-80d6-466f0cf542a3"
  1 => "2019-12-13 12:14:09"
  2 => "d362be96-e717-4204-8b2c-f36c2bb6004b"
]
"time" => 1.02
```

]

But since all my uuid were empty (since I just created the column just before) the where part was making an update on all my rows. I just don't understand why it's not using my initial primary key which was an incrementing id but I guess it has something to do with the way Eloquent is running the queries.

To achieve what I was looking for I must instead build my query this way (a bit less elegant but...)

```
 $retailerBrands = App\RetailerBrand::all();

    foreach($retailerBrands as $retailerBrand){
        $brandId = $retailerBrand->id;
        RetailerBrand::where('id', '=', $brandId)->update(['uuid' => Uuid::generate(4)->string]);
    }
```

Thank you anyway to the guys who try to help me :)